# How to ask confirmation when closing a window?

Tags: javascript

I want to pop up a message asking for confirmation if the user wants to leave the current page, exactly like stackoverflow does it when you are typing a question.

Could someone help me on this, by giving me a script or redirecting me to an answer (on this site or elsewhere) ?

Thanks

Comment: Would it be inpolite to suggest that you just look at the source for stackoverflow?

Comment: Not to be rude but did you actually search for an answer first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the window's [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)  event and return a confirmation message as a string.

## `onunload` will *not* work here.  [Demo](http://jsbin.com/obizu3)

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `onbeforeunload` event.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return 'Are you sure that you want to leave this page?';
};
```

Comment: Or try declarative syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132760/how-to-ask-confirmation-when-closing-a-window/2132790#2132790

Comment: You need to return a string, not call `confirm`.

Comment: This works, but be aware that although most browsers will use the return value in the popup some browsers like Firefox will not use it and instead use the default popup. More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

Answer (score 1):

window.onbeforeunload Seems to work for IE, but something like

```
window.onunload = function()
{
    if (confirm('Save changes?'))
        document.forms['form1'].submit();
};
```

Seems to work for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store all the values of your fields in some variables & check them whenever use changes the page url or clicks on some link, to trap the page change event use page unload event.

Page unload event link/ sample http://help.dottoro.com/ljflhicd.php.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't this work?

```
<body onunload="return confirm('really quit?');">
```

Also for framesets by the way...