# Custom dialog box to get confirmation when browser tab is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ask confirmation when closing a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132760/how-to-ask-confirmation-when-closing-a-window)

I would like to display a confirmation box and a custom message when the browser tab is closed. Users can click OK to actually close the tab, and CANCEL to stay on the page.

The following is my code. Can someone tell me how I can make it work?

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'ARE you sure?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'ARE you sure?';
};
```

Comment: close browser tab and get confirm message.

Comment: not all browsers provide same level of support for custom message. Did you try searching this site or google....lots of information

Answer (score 2):

Try this one then

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Sure?';
};
```

Comment: your code is working but default message come.This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved. i want to display my custom message

Comment: What do you mean default message?

Comment: This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved. i want to display my custom message

Comment: here is default message is that:This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved. thats place i want my own message

Comment: @DivyangParekh, custom message comes in Google Chrome and INternet Explorer only. Not sure about Safari

Comment: @DivyangParekh  not all browser provide message support... this is a very simple topic to research on this site or in google

Comment: @charlietfl : hello..i am do all this things and then i coming Stackoverflow

Comment: Change `return 'Sure?';` for `return confirm('Sure?');`