# How to prevent (hold the refresh button) DoS Attack

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

My website is very dynamic and its collecting data from the database. while I was testing I pressed the refresh key and hold it for some time, the server went down. (This is a simple DoS attack). How can I stop user to keep hitting the refresh button.
Can anyone tell me the solution for that. Like gmail does, go to gmail account and press <kbd>F5</kbd> and hold it for some time. Gmail will display this message

**"We’re sorry, but your Gmail account is temporarily unavailable. We apologize for the inconvenience and suggest trying again in a few minutes. You can view the Apps Status Dashboard for the current status of the service."**

Thanks

Comment: Your "hold F5" issue is nothing compared to a million users doing a single page load on Google. Thus, you should try looking at the bigger picture. Review your server code, do optimizations and find out that bottleneck that causes it to crash instead of finding a solution to a single, negligible problem.

Comment: In JavaScript you could raise a prompt effectively asking the user "Are you sure?", see the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2132760/1615483). Then remove the listener after some timeout. (This won't stop it if they've turned off JavaScript or haven't loaded the page in their browser, obviously)

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer: I am not comparing google with my webApp, and my application does not crash. I am collecting data from sensor in real time which is a huge amount of data, and then I do some calculations on that data, this takes some time. for instance, If I press F5 for 30 seconds, the webApp goes down for some time (1-2 minutes).

Comment: Please elaborate more on your methodology, rather than giving a vague overview. It would be better if you post actual code, state the data flow, what entities are involved etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the counter approach. Increase it till a threshold is reached within a small interval and if so then block access.

The JSP for it would be something like this

```
 <% 
        int refresh;
        if(session.getAttribute("pageRefresh")==null)
             refresh=0;
        else
            refresh = (Integer)session.getAttribute("pageRefresh") + 1;


       session.setAttribute("pageRefresh", refresh); 

       session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10000);

       if (refresh>100)
       {
           //error message or black list client
       }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use mod_evasive or mod_qos or mod_security
I prefer mod_security [modsecurity_crs_11_dos_protection](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/experimental_rules/modsecurity_crs_11_dos_protection.conf)